# Is it "best practice" to do an AJAX call from a controller?

Tags: angularjs, mvvm

In an MVC framework, the data are handled in the model.

In AngularJs, is it common to handle the data directly in a controller, or should it be done in a service instead?

Comment: Best practice would be storing data in a service. But if it's just small amount of data and the data is not used in other places, controller is fine.

Comment: @sza This is an interesting post, but that doesn't really answer my question

Answer (score 6):

There is no harm in firing XHRs from within a controller if controller is the only one using the call.

But if multiple controllers need to make the same call you would better move it inside a service for ease of access.

Comment: This is what I do, I just wanted to know what purists think about it. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: u said move ajax call in service due to ease of access. why not to move the ajax call in factrory.....please tell me the reason why avoid factor for this purpose?